# Multiple Excel with different schema Upload in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a task to import multiple Excel files in their respective sql server tables. The Excel files are of different schema and I need a mechanism to create a table dynamically; so that I don't have to write a Create Table query. I use SSIS, and I have seen some SSIS articles on the same. However, it looks I have to define the table anyhow. OpenRowSet doesn't work well in case of large excel files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using BiML, which dynamically creates packages based on meta data.

The only other possible solution is to write a script task.